# How to get base url with language in joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla3.0

Trying to get base url in joomla with language suffix like `http://localhost/projectname/en`
We can easily get `http://localhost/projectname/` by using `JURI::base`

how to get project url with language like

```
 http://localhost/projectname/en
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo $this->baseurl . $this->language;

==> this would give full name of language for ex,en-gb

to avoid this use

if ($this->language == "en-gb")

{

$sef = "en";

}

echo $this->baseurl . $sef;